# How can I add multilingual taxonomy breadcrumbs?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, i18n-l10n, breadcrumbs

I have a site with two languages and a large number of taxonomy terms.  I want to use breadcrumbs on my taxonomy pages, but I can't find a system that works well with multiple languages.

I translated my taxonomy terms with the Entity Translation module, using the field method.  What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by making a content pane in Views.  Here's what you need to do.

1. For hierarchical taxonomies, determine the maximum depth.  Example: United States -> Illinois -> Chicago (child, parent, and grandparent)
2. Create a view showing fields of taxonomy terms.  Add a contextual filter: *Taxonomy term: Term ID*.  For **When the filter value is NOT available**, choose *Provide default value* of *Taxonomy term ID from URL* and leave *Load default filter from term page* checked.
3. Add a relationship of *Taxonomy term: parent term*.  Do this as many times as you need to get to the maximum possible depth.  Do not require the relationship because the term may be a root term.  To make sure that you can keep track of all the relationships even though they will be of the same type, when adding the relationship, click *More* at the bottom of the add dialog and type in an appropriate name (parent, grandparent, great-grandparent, etc.) for the **Administrative title**.
4. Add the taxonomy term name field (the one provided by the Title module, since we are using Entity translation).  Don't use a relationship.  As the administrative title, set "current page term" or something easy to remember.
5. Now to get the parent and grandparent terms.  First, add a term id for each relationship (parent, grandparent, etc.)  Make sure to uncheck *create a label* and check *Exclude from display*.  Make sure to set the proper relationship for each tid.
6. Then, add the taxonomy term name field again as many times as necessary so that you have a name field for each relationship.  Again, make sure to set the relationship each time you add a new field.  Also, for each term name that has a relationship, make sure that *Hide rewriting if empty* is checked under **No results behavior**.  Under **Rewrite results**, check *Output this field as a link* and enter `taxonomy/term/[tid]` where `[tid]` is the replacement pattern for the appropriate relationship.
7. Reorder the fields from "oldest" (grandparent) to "youngest" (current term).
8. Under **Format**, click *Settings* next to *Fields*.  Check the boxes next to all of the non-tid fields to make them inline fields.  Add the separator of your choice and you're done!