# Multilingual Breadcrumb

Tags: 7, breadcrumbs

I need to show a breadcrumb on my client website but it is required to be in two languages I have tried several approaches and modules but all of it show the breadcrumb in one language only.

Please, If anyone have an idea about this I appreciate your help.

Besides, Could you please explain more about using default drupal breadcrumb what should I have been installed to use breadcrumb correctly? Do I need breadcrumb + another module ???

Regards,

Comment: You need to give details about where you are placing the breadcrumb and how you are translating your site.  That said, this answer may be of use: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/59930/how-can-i-add-multilingual-taxonomy-breadcrumbs-in-panels

Comment: Thanks Patrick, I am using taxonomy to categorize my content with localized vocabulary, and I am using the default taxonomy term view to display categorized content. 

I have installed easy breadcrumb but is display the breadcrumb only in English.

Comment: Most breadcrumb modules on drupal.org do not have multilingual capability.  Unless a module specifically lists itself as having support, I would assume that there is no support.

Comment: Crumbs has some level of multilingual capability (we are using it with translated menu links, not sure about vocabularies).
I would try that one first, create an issue for missing stuff

Comment: +1 to Crumbs. So far the only thing to really work "out of the box" to get translated breadcrumbs. It also seems to be the best module to provide a structured approach to coding separate breadcrumb recipes.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want your breadcrumbs like this:

```
  Home/La Casa >> Node/Nodo >> Friends/Amigos
```

You could override template_preprocess_breadcrumb like so:

```
  function MY_THEME_preprocess_breadcrumb(&$variables)
  {
     $breadcrumbs = &$variables['breadcrumb'];
     foreach($breadcrumbs as &$breadcrumb)
     {
         $breadcrumb .= '/' . locale($breadcrumb, null, 'SP');
     }
   }
```

Don't quote me on the langcodes, and this would require that you have the locale module installed and enabled, but it should output the above example breadcrumb.

Answer (score 1):

I used [Custom Breadcrumbs](https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_breadcrumbs) Module it has the ability to add breadcrumb for each language... For breadcrumbs which are automatically generated translation can be done in String Translation Table. I think multilingual breadcrumb can also be created using [Path Breadcrumbs](https://www.drupal.org/project/path_breadcrumbs)

Answer (score 0):

Drupal has some mainstream contributed modules that can handle this in most cases.  Using built-in interface translation and i18n_string, you can add translations for many of the main breadcrumbs in Configuration -> Regional & Language -> Translate Interface -> Translate.

Several modules can help you get these strings to begin with.  You can use the potx module to pull all built-in interface strings from your other installed modules, which puts the strings into the locales_source table.  Then you can use the l10n_update module to search for community-contributed translations for these strings.

For the last part of a breadcrumb that comes from a node, for example, Drupal will display the translated title of the node if it finds it.  For Content Translation (node-based), the node displays its title in the breadcrumb, and for Entity Translation (field-based), you can enable the title module to convert the title property to a field, which can then be translated and displayed in the breadcrumb.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
<?php
    //breadcrumb fix
        function THEME_NAME_menu_breadcrumb_alter(&$active_trail, $item) {
            global $language ;
            $lang_name = $language->language;
            $i = 0;
            foreach (array_keys($active_trail) as $key) {
                if($i!=0){
                    $translatedValue = i18n_string_translate(array('menu', 'item', $active_trail[$key]['mlid'], 'title'), $active_trail[$key]['title'], array('langcode' => $lang_name, 'sanitize' => FALSE));
                    $active_trail[$key]['title'] = $translatedValue;
                }
               $i++;
            }
        } 
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the `i18n` module, including submodule `i18n_menu`, then the most reliable way of translating your breadcrumbs would be implementing `hook_menu_breadcrumb_alter` and run `_i18n_menu_link_title` function on each item.

This should work:

```
/**
 *   Implements hook_menu_breadcrumb_alter()
 */
function YOURMODULE_menu_breadcrumb_alter(&$active_trail, $item) {
  foreach ($active_trail as $index => $breadcrumb_item) {
    if (isset($breadcrumb_item['mlid'])) {
      $active_trail[$index]['title'] = _i18n_menu_link_title($breadcrumb_item);
    }
  }
}
```